# Do transformers make batteries more dangerous

Tags: batteries, transformer

I have connected 8 AA batteries to a transformer to make a shocker. I don't know the exact transformer, but it has 5 pins, and I got it from an old 1950's radio. Does this make the battery pack any more dangerous, and could it hurt the heart more? I know the transformer raises the volts and decreases the amps, and dont Amps kill, so why does it shock more. This may be a dumb question, but better safe than dead!
Thanks, skyler

Comment: This is an overly vague question even if you ignore the context. We cannot comment on an arbitrary circuit using an arbitrary transformer, and I personally take issue with a 'shocker' being built by anyone, especially an amateur. This question should be closed.

Comment: So bear with me while I try to understand this more...  You connected some batteries to a transformer that you know nothing about.  But you don't even know how transformers in general work.  In an attempt to shock other people without shocking yourself in the process.  But you don't know what makes things "shocking" or "dangerous".  Right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> better safe than dead

I'm glad that's how you feel about it too. But in that case I'd say: **don't**. You know nothing about the components you're using (the transformer), and probably don't even know how it works (not on DC).

If you're interested in electronics I would suggest to learn about basic components, like resistors, capacitors and transistors, and think of something more constructive than trying to hurt others.

Comment: Possible Darwin award in the future for @skyler